# Error on child(localKey).setValue(item) to update firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I set :

```
private Query requests;
```

For a query on Firebase:

```
requests = db.getReference("Requests")
                .orderByChild("status")
                .endAt("1");
```

And on update to set a value give me a error on:

```
requests.child(localKey).setValue(item);
```

because before I had just

```
DatabaseReference requests;
```

and

```
requests=db.getReference("Requests");
```

How do I change that? Any help is welcome.

Error on Build:

```
requests.child(localKey).setValue(item);
                            ^
  symbol:   method child(String)
  location: variable requests of type Query
```

Answer (score 0):

The following object:

```
requests = db.getReference("Requests")
                .orderByChild("status")
                .endAt("1");
```

Is an object of type [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query). As you can see, inside the class there is **no** setValue() method. So that's the reason why you cannot perform such an operation. On the other hand, DatabaseReference class does contain a [setValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)) method. If you want, however, to use setValue() on the objects that are returned by a query, then you should attach a listener as in the following lines of code:

```
requests.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                ds.getRef().setValue(item);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Please note that setValue():

> Set the data at this location to the given value.

That being said, I think that you'll be more interested in using the [updateChildren(Map<String, Object> update)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method, which:

> Update the specific child keys to the specified values.

This means that will not override the data at the existing location.

Comment: Please don't provide an answer instead of comments. You get an error most likely because you're not using the latest dependencies. Please update them and tell me if it works, ok?

Comment: Please edit your question and add that code in a formatted way, so we can see it better. Besides that, I tell you again that you cannot call `setValue()` on a `Query` object. Have even tried the code in my answer?

Comment: i m using de getRef of firebase on project, but on this class i want a Query.. i have this on that code to confirm; `alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged") @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { dialog.dismiss(); item.setStatus(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedIndex())); if (item.getStatus().equals("2")) {db.getReference(Common.ORDER_NEED_SHIP_TABLE) .child(shipperSpinner.getItems().get(shipperSpinner.getSelectedIndex()).toString()).child(localKey)setValue(item); `

Comment: `alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged") @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { dialog.dismiss(); item.setStatus(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedIndex())); if (item.getStatus().equals("2")) {db.getReference(Common.ORDER_NEED_SHIP_TABLE) .child(shipperSpinner.getItems().get(shipperSpinner.getSelectedIndex()).toString()).child(localKey)setValue(item);`
so I put the code in your answer instead of:
  `requests.child(localKey).setValue(item);`
i put the code in your answer

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: i tried, i cant get it.. i put the code in your answer but at `get().` cannot resolve in `Query`.
i think its becuse this one : `db.getReference(Common.ORDER_NEED_SHIP_TABLE)                          .child(shipperSpinner.getItems().get(shipperSpinner.getSelectedIndex()).toString())
  .child(localKey)
  .setValue(item);`

Comment: What exactly can't you get? Do you have an error? What is the error?

Comment: I cant set the positive spinner on this 
`alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged") @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { dialog.dismiss(); item.setStatus(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedIndex())); if (item.getStatus().equals("2")) {db.getReference(Common.ORDER_NEED_SHIP_TABLE) .child(shipperSpinner.getItems().get(shipperSpinner.getSelectedIndex()).toString()).child(localKey)setValue(item)`
then the code in your answer that i change for `requests.child(localKey).setValue(item);`

Comment: Assume that `requests.get().addOnCompleteListener.. ` is not from a query..
This is the error it gives me:
`symbol: method get()
  location: variable requests of type Query `

Comment: What type of object is `requests`?

Comment: Hi @Alex Mamo,  requests its a query 
`private Query requests;`  

` requests = db.getReference("Requests")
                .orderByChild("status")
                .endAt("1");  `
of firebase, before i had `DatabaseReference requests;` and `requests=db.getReference("Requests");`

Comment: Ok, there should be no issues. What does not work the way you expect now?

Comment: gives me: this error ` symbol: method get()   location: variable requests of type Query `
i put the in your answer :
` requests.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                ds.getRef().setValue(item);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
}); `

after :

Comment: `alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
item.setStatus(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedIndex()));
if (item.getStatus().equals("2")) {
db.getReference(Common.ORDER_NEED_SHIP_TABLE)
.child(shipperSpinner.getItems().get(shipperSpinner.getSelectedIndex()).toString())
                            .child(localKey)
                            .setValue(item);`